# Install/Uninstall Zabbix with Powershell in c:\Program files(x86)\zabbix folder

Tags: powershell, zabbix

in order to distribute Zabbix in our company, I would like to create a function for the Zabbix 5.2 client in my installation script.
This also means that zabbix_agentd.exe is registered as a service with the associated parameters.
I am apparently too stupid to do this with the start-process.

The following line serves as an example .. I've tried a few things but couldn't find a suitable quotation, etc.

start-process -FilePath cmd.exe -ArgumentList "/c c:\program files (x86)\zabbix\zabbix_agend.exe --config C:\Program Files (x86)\Zabbix\zabbix_agentd.win.conf --install"

I also hope that I can transfer the path to zabbix_agentd.exe as a variable

Ih hope someone has a tip.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For Windows I use the MSI for installations and check the registry if the correct version is already installed else upgrade.

Replace  and  for your own.

```
$zabbixversion = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Zabbix SIA\Zabbix Agent (64-bit)").ProductVersion

if ($zabbixversion -eq "5.0.20.2400") {
write-host "Zabbix already installed"
exit
}
else 
{
write-host "Uninstall Zabbix Agent"
msiexec /uninstall \\<share>\zabbix_agent-5.0.20-windows-amd64-openssl.msi server=<SERVERIP> sport=10050 lport=10050 SERVERACTIVE=<SERVERIP> rmtcmd=0

write-host "Installing Zabbix Agent"
msiexec /I \\<share>\\zabbix_agent-5.0.20-windows-amd64-openssl.msi server=<SERVERIP> sport=10050 lport=10050 SERVERACTIVE=<SERVERIP> rmtcmd=0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [MSI package](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/installation/install_from_packages/win_msi) instead.

You can specify as parameters the host name/ip address of the server, the remote command support, the psk support etc...

You can then launch it with cmd/powershell or even better via GPO

See the [documentation page](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/installation/install_from_packages/win_msi) for some of examples

Comment: Many thanks for your response.

I still have the old agent running as a service on many clients, which I would like to remove first with the --uninstall command.
Do you have another idea here?

Comment: Try manually with the msi on a box wich has the old agent: if the installer detects it,you can use the new package to remove the old (ie: with `msiexec /x ....` through the command line), or to overwrite the installation